# How to insert data into Excel if the column name contains '#' in c#

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-3.0, oledb

I am able to insert values into my Excel file using `c#` successfully. 
But when my column name contains "#" (for example `Target_Group#`), I get this error:

> Unknown column name

But in my Excel the column name should be "Target_Group# "
My insert query is:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] ([Target_Group#]) VALUES('OHMCRWP0')";
```

I am using `OLEDB connections`

Comment: I am not sure but column name can not include `#` character.

Comment: @शेखर column names with `#` are valid in SQL Server And also for Excel when you are reading, But it's not valid just for Excel when you try to `ExecuteNonCoery`, And also in sheet names ;).